# SpecFlow and BDD in ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bdd, specflow

I am writing some BDD style Spec Flow test which is working out smoothly! Now, I am in a position to test that the data annotations validations are fired. I am thinking that this test should be performed by using WatiN tool since the UpdateModel is fired when the values from the form are posted.

How do you test that the validations are firing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can do this.  You dont have to use WatiN to check validations, I am using SpecFlow to call controller methods and then interrogate the ModelState property checking for the errors I expected to be raised from the invalid data I entered.

You can also use WatiN to check that particular error text is displayed on screen by attatching to the browser and using the Find.ByText("Error Message") method.

If you haven't already I strongly suggest having a read of this article, helped me alot when starting out with SpecFlow/WatiN and BDD:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490346.aspx

Hope that helps.

Comment: But if you are using DataAnnotations on your ViewModel properties how do you fire the validations?

Answer (score 0):

By testing them with invalid data...(and valid data)

If your model has an annotate just fire values at it you may write a scenario like

```
Scenario: Adding an invalid user   
GIVEN I am in the add user page  
AND I have not filled in the  name   
WHEN I Add  
THEN I should see the error defined in my annotation
```

more on testing annotations is here http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/04/dataannotations-and-aspnet-mvc.html
but you just want them to fire. Remember you are testing from the outside in this case.